# Why div space is not the same on Chrome in Windows?

Tags: html, css

I add space (margin-bottom: 2px) between each li elements. I found they are not the same space on Chrome/Firefox in windows like the image below. Any clues?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/wasichris/pen/gOWPEJw)

```
<ul class="c-side-tool">
  <li class="c-side-tool__item">TOP</li>
  <li class="c-side-tool__item">TOP</li>
  <li class="c-side-tool__item">TOP</li>
  <li class="c-side-tool__item">TOP</li>
  <li class="c-side-tool__item">TOP</li>
  <li class="c-side-tool__item">TOP</li>
</ul>

.c-side-tool {
  &__item {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    height: 33px;
  }
}
```

Image - Different space between li

[image]

Comment: Are you using "Ctrl+" to check? I see it fine if I give a zoom of 150% or more, but I when I set it to 125% I see the spacing like the image you attached (Chrome, Windows).

Comment: Try using `margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;`. By doing so, you specify that there is no margin on the tops of your `li`s.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Finally I found the reason, plz check my answer below.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with the code. It's just your screen resolution that's causing the problem. The li's are not aligned to the pixel grid.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found it. I got different space on screen because of the Windows scale and layout. My setting is 175%, after I set it back to 200% and the issue is solved.

scale and layout setting in my win10 [image]